# How to read a leaderboard from a text file and sort from lowest score to highest?

Tags: python-3.x, text-files

I have a reflex test game and have setup a text file that stores the user's name and score with a space in between. How do I sort the text file numerically so that the lowest numbers are at the top and highest at the bottom

E.g

Ben 1.43

Eric 3.53

Steve 7.45

I want to include the 2 decimals places.

Code:

```
import time
import random
global start
global end
global score
def gameBegin():
    print('***************')
    print('* Reflex Game *')
    print('***************')
    print("\nPress Enter as soon as you see the word 'stop'.")
    print('Press Enter to Begin')
    input()

def gameStart():
    global start
    global end
    time.sleep(random.randint(1,1))
    start = time.time()
    input('STOP')
    end = time.time()
def gameScore():
    global start
    global end
    global score
    score=round(end-start,2)
    print (score)

def scorePrint():
    global score
    with open("Leaderboards.txt", "r+") as board:
        print (board.read())


def boardEdit():
    global score
    name = input('Enter Your Name For The Leader Board : ')
    board = open ("Leaderboards.txt","a+")
    board.write(name )
    board.write(" ")
    board.write(str(score) )
def boardSort():
    #HELP 

gameBegin()
gameStart()
gameScore()
scorePrint()
boardEdit()
boardSort()
```

Answer (score 1):

look at this link https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting
this will help you with any kind of sort you need.

but to do what you are asking you would need to perform a sort before printing the leaderboard

A simple ascending sort is very easy -- just call the sorted() function. It returns a new sorted list:

```
sorted([5, 2, 3, 1, 4])
```

then becomes

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

You can also use the list.sort() method of a list. It modifies the list in-place (and returns None to avoid confusion). Usually it's less convenient than sorted() - but if you don't need the original list, it's slightly more efficient.

```
>>>a = [5, 2, 3, 1, 4]
>>>a.sort()
>>>a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: i have edited my answer please let me know if i need to make any more changes to make it an efficient answer

Comment: How do I sort the text file though?

Comment: you would have to open and read the text file from your script then perform the sort and then write the new data to the file and close the file ALL within the script your writing

Comment: Thanks, I’ll give it all a try later tonight when I finish class and then post the code